# bypass system call c++

Tags: c++, system-calls

I was writing a c++ function something like this:

```
while（true）｛
 function A（)
 system（cmd）
 function B（)
｝
```

I was doing a system call between two functions and this system call will take a very long time to execute. Is it possible the let it running in the background and bypass it to execute function B at the same time?

Comment: Lookup `std::thread` et al.

Comment: `system()` is a security nightmare - prefer to stay away from it. Also, the term "[system call](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)" usually means something different from a call to the `system` function.

Comment: What happens if the loop comes around before the first call completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux/Unix, [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) uses a shell for running `cmd`. This means, you can append an [ampersand `&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) to run the command in the background, e.g.

```
const char cmd[] = "some_command &";
while（true）｛
    functionA();
    system(cmd);
    functionB();
｝
```

---

Be aware, that since this is running in a loop `while (true) {...}`, you might overflow your system with too many background processes.

Comment: Thanks. I have condition to check before running the system call but you suggestion definitely helps.